# How can I do with tomcat deployment by IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Ia am newbie using Intellij. I do know why for my scenario. Any one know the reason?
**My scenario:**

- I build my web application. ( build war file, war exploded successfully)
**case 1:**

- I add my web application on tomcat instance in Intellij **correctly**. Add my war file example.war - start - failed
**case 2:**

- I copy the war file to external tomcat - start - successfully.

**On Intellij:**
- Debug view- Output:

> NO ERROR

- idea.log

```
.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\03.sonat\02.cc\workforce\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\WebTemplate_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.loadXMLFile(TomcatUtil.java:171)
 ... 31 more
2017-02-24 15:45:26,140 [3049638]   INFO - tbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil - Cannot load D:\03.sonat\02.cc\workforce\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\WebTemplate_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml: D:\03.sonat\02.cc\workforce\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\WebTemplate_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified) 
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Cannot load D:\03.sonat\02.cc\workforce\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\WebTemplate_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml: D:\03.sonat\02.cc\workforce\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\WebTemplate_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.loadXMLFile(TomcatUtil.java:178)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.findContextInContextXml(TomcatUtil.java:98)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.findContextElement(TomcatUtil.java:352)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$4.doPerform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:128)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$DeployStep.perform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:289)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.doDeploy(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:131)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$4.doPerform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:124)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$JmxOperation.perform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:247)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.doStartDeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:139)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$2.setDeploymentStatus(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:94)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$DeploymentModelOperation.doSetDeploymentStatus(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:274)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$3.doPerform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:104)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$JmxOperation.perform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:247)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.doStartDeployWithUndeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:111)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.startDeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:78)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminServerBase.startDeploy(TomcatAdminServerBase.java:119)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.startDeploy(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:101)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.a(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:56)
 at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.b(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:104)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.runFirstTaskThenPollAndRunRest(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:178)
 at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$000(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:40)
 at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:197)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at .lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\example_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.loadXMLFile(TomcatUtil.java:171)
 ... 31 more
2017-02-24 15:45:26,140 [3049638]   INFO - tbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil - Cannot load D:\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\example_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml: D:\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\example_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified) 
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Cannot load D:\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\example_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml: D:\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\example_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.loadXMLFile(TomcatUtil.java:178)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.findContextInContextXml(TomcatUtil.java:98)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.findContextElement(TomcatUtil.java:352)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$4.doPerform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:128)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$DeployStep.perform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:289)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.doDeploy(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:131)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$4.doPerform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:124)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$JmxOperation.perform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:247)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.doStartDeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:139)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$2.setDeploymentStatus(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:94)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$DeploymentModelOperation.doSetDeploymentStatus(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:274)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$3.doPerform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:104)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$JmxOperation.perform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:247)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.doStartDeployWithUndeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:111)
 at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.startDeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:78)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminServerBase.startDeploy(TomcatAdminServerBase.java:119)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.startDeploy(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:101)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.a(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:56)
 at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.b(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:104)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.runFirstTaskThenPollAndRunRest(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:178)
 at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$000(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:40)
 at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:197)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\ProjectTemplate\WebTemplate\out\artifacts\example_war_exploded\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.TomcatUtil.loadXMLFile(TomcatUtil.java:171)
 ... 30
```

What's happen?

Comment: Forget this approach. Take a look at spring-boot instead.

Comment: what do you mean? Do not forget that I can start the war file with external tomcat

Comment: Your approach is half-a-decade out of date. You should google 'spring-boot' and adopt the approach documented there. Its a lot faster/easier than the approach you are currently using, and even better, if you follow the simple instructions on the spring-boot site, it'll just work, first time, like magic.

Comment: Is that a clean unmodified Tomcat installation? Deploy from IDE may fail if startup scripts or configs of your Tomcat were modified. If it's not the case, share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, I do not modify any Tomcat's configurations.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I found out the way to start tomcat successfully in Intellij.
- Exit Intellij
- Open task manager 
- Find the java process - End process
- Re-open Intellij
- Start tomcat server

Let's try the way for your the same case.